# IMG won't hover

Tags: html, css, hover

As you can see by my code, I am creating several different links in the shape of a circle, these links have an image, however when you hover the image, I want it to change the image to something else.

However when I try to hover it will not work? :S

CSS:

```
.Row {
width:16%; 
height:250px; 
text-align:center; 
margin-top:25px;
margin-left:130px; 
float:left; 
display:block; 
border:0px solid red; 
overflow:hidden; 
 } 

 .Google {
width:240px; 
height:240px; 
text-align:center; 
border:5px solid white; 
border-radius:300px;
margin:auto; 
background-image:url("img/googlet.png"); 
 }

 .Google:hover {
background-image:url("img/outlook.png"); 
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="Row"> 
<a href="http://google.co.uk"> <div class="Google"></div> </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle or anything similar?

Comment: maybe try using `a:hover .Google` instead of `.Google:hover` ?

Comment: Your code is working: http://jsfiddle.net/A4Dut/ , changed only image. Maybe you have some invincible div over `.Row` and that's why you can't hover link?

Comment: Just about to say the same as Justinas, works for me too: http://jsfiddle.net/7sNRH/

Comment: And your HTML is not valid. `<a>` is inline element, and can't have block elements inside. Use `<div><a></a></div>` and css `a{display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 100%}`

Comment: It's valid if it's html5 http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Answer (score 0):

You can block a tag with a {display:block;}

than write css for hover like following.

> a:hover .Google {background-image:url("img/outlook.png");}